# How to merge array objects based on 2 keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my code

```js
var array = [{
    OrderId: "L01",
    Location: "London"
    Qty: "6.00",
    Status: "Product A
  },
  {
    OrderId: "L01",
    Location: "London"
    Qty: "2.00"
    Status: "Product B"
  },
  {
    OrderId: "L01",
    Location: "London"
    Qty: "3.00"
    Status: "Product C"
  },
  {
    OrderId: "P01",
    Location: "Paris"
    Qty: "7.00"
    Status: "Product A"
  },
  {
    OrderId: "P01",
    Location: "Paris"
    Qty: "4.00"
    Status: "Product B"
  },
  {
    OrderId: "P01",
    Location: "Paris"
    Qty: "9.00"
    Status: "Product C"
  }
];
```

I want to convert this array to

```
var arrayModified = [{
    OrderId: "L01",
    Location: "London"
    QtyA: "6.00",
    QtyB: "2.00,
    QtyC: "3.00
  },
  {
    OrderId: "P01",
    Location: "London"
    Qty: A "7.00",
    QtyB: "4.00",
    QtyC: "9.00"
  }
];
```

Basically i want to check variable called status and based on that I have to create new fields QtyA, QtyB, QtyC. OrderId and Plant are common and unique fields.

How can I achieve this functionality in plain JS without Jquery and Lodash.

Comment: How would jquery even help in this case?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array Just use one of the appropriate functions for arrays. Play around a little bit, and when you got some code to show, edit your questions.

Comment: Shouldn't the second object in the expected output be "P01" and "Paris"?

Comment: @holydragon yes you are correct

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
var array = [{OrderId:"L01",Location:"London",Qty:"6.00",Status:"Product A"},{OrderId:"L01",Location:"London",Qty:"2.00",Status:"Product B"},{OrderId:"L01",Location:"London",Qty:"3.00",Status:"Product C"},{OrderId:"P01",Location:"Paris",Qty:"7.00",Status:"Product A"},{OrderId:"P01",Location:"Paris",Qty:"4.00",Status:"Product B"},{OrderId:"P01",Location:"Paris",Qty:"9.00",Status:"Product C"}];

const merged = array.reduce((r,{OrderId, Location, Status, Qty}) => {
  const [p,suffix] = Status.split("Product ")
  r[OrderId] = r[OrderId] || {OrderId, Location};
  r[OrderId]["Qty"+suffix] =  Qty;
  return r;
},{})

const output = Object.values(merged)

console.log(output)
```

The goal is to create an `accumulator` object with each unique `OrderId` as key. Split the `Status` at `"Product "` and use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to take the second item from the resulting array in `suffix` variable. (Or you can simply use replace: `var suffix = Status.replace("Product ", "")`). Then use `Object.values` to get the value of this object to an array.

`merged`/accumulator looks like this:

```
{
  "L01": {
    "OrderId": "L01",
    "Location": "London",
    "QtyA": "6.00",
    "QtyB": "2.00",
    "QtyC": "3.00"
  },
  "P01": {
    "OrderId": "P01",
    "Location": "Paris",
    "QtyA": "7.00",
    "QtyB": "4.00",
    "QtyC": "9.00"
  }
}
```

(Please PLEASE make sure you have a valid input data. There were missing commas and quotes. I wasn't sure if there was issue with my code or the input.)

Comment: i am still trying to get my head around working with the reduce function. Can you explain the currentValue a bit more please? I mean... did you just hand in the structure and the reduce function knows how to handle it? Also, what is [p,suffix]?? you are declaring a variable with this, but what is this p? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you able to declare variables from an array with this??? p = "" and suffix = "<productLetter>"??

Comment: `reduce` is like a for loop but with an accumulator object or array. Each iteration I'm updating the accumulator based on the `Status` and `OrderId`. The second parameter to the `reduce` is the current item being loope through. I'm using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to split them into variables. Since `split` returns 2 values, you can use array destructing to get the second item in the array. That's the ` [p,suffix]` syntax

Comment: @JustAMicrobe that's [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). We can actually skip the first declaration since we only care about the alphabet at index = 1. like this: `[ , suffix] = Status.split("Product ")`

Comment: @JustAMicrobe I recommend going through the MDN link in the comment. It's introduced in ES6 and it's very useful

Comment: i am on it! This is pretty usefull stuff to know! Thanks again